# How can we add app widgets as a premium feature option on Android

Tags: android, mobile, widget

We want to create a few app widgets in android for our mobile application. As of now, I followed the tutorial and can create app widgets and add them to the Home screen. However I would like to know if it's possible to show the app widget in the list of widgets to add, and then show the premium screen for the user to pay up, if he's not a premium user. The intent here is to show all the user the list of widgets and if they want to add it, show them the screen to upgrade to Premium if they are not already a premium user. Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to me is to add layer on top of the each widget and hide it if user already has premium subscription. The layer contains button "buy premium" and opens app's premium activity page.
But may be there are more neat way to do it

Comment: Thnaks, I was wondering if there is an easier way to do any configuration or anything that make it only available to premium users.

Comment: you can hide part of a widgets if premium was not purchased such as
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364402/is-it-possible-to-have-a-widget-which-is-only-useable-when-the-user-has-unlocked

Comment: or may be have a look here
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets/configuration